# Objective-C How can I localize Time Duration: "1 Year", "2 Years", "3 Years", etc

Tags: ios, iphone, date, localization, nsdateformatter

I need to localize all possibilities of:
1 Year,
2 Years, and On... (up to any number).

1 Month,
2 Months, and On... (up to any number).

In various languages, the word: "Years" changes based on the number in front of it.  Such as in french:

22 Years = 22 ans

23 Years = 23 années

So I can't use string substitution in the NSLocalizedString pattern such as:  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"MY_KEY_NAME_%lu_%@",  amount, unitOfMeasure];
(Because the unit of measure is dependent on the amount).

I've been looking at NSDateFormatter, but I don't see any placeholder that can do: "# Years" or "# Months".

Do you guys know an easy way to localize this?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: This is supposed to be possible with `NSDateComponentsFormatter`. However in a quick test, it produces both "22 ans" and "23 ans", so it's buggy with regard to localizations.

Comment: Are you sure about those plurals? I wondered about them so I asked about it over on Stack Exchange's French language site: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/17890/9532 There wasn't much support for switching between "ans" and "années" based on the number.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.  I have obtained these from Google Translate.  Perhaps it's incorrect.   Google Translate is producing "annees" for everything ending in 3,4,5 (Except the teens).   I know for a fact a similar thing happens in other languages like Russian.  "1 god, 2 goda, 3 goda, 4 goda, 5 let, 6 let, etc"  (different words even based on number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd do this using `NSDateComponentsFormatter` which, after some research, is apparently **not** buggy here and does the right thing in at least a couple of different languages.

You'd create the formatter with something like

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnit.Year
formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyle.Full
```

Then for a simple test try something like

```
let now = NSDate()
for yearsAhead in (1...30) {
    let newDate = lendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Year, value: yearsAhead, toDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchNextTime)
    let duration = formatter.stringFromDate(now, toDate: newDate!)
    print("\(newDate): \(duration)")
}
```

With the device language set to French this uses "ans" for all values >1, which is apparently correct:

```
2017-02-24 17:39:53 +0000: 1 an
2018-02-24 17:39:53 +0000: 2 ans
2019-02-24 17:39:53 +0000: 3 ans
2020-02-24 17:39:53 +0000: 4 ans
2021-02-24 17:39:53 +0000: 5 ans
2022-02-24 17:39:53 +0000: 6 ans
....
```

With the device language set to Russian it uses different plurals for different numbers, as you noted, and using Cyrillic characters:

```
2017-02-24 17:41:29 +0000: 1 год
2018-02-24 17:38:38 +0000: 2 года
2019-02-24 17:38:38 +0000: 3 года
2020-02-24 17:38:38 +0000: 4 года
2021-02-24 17:38:38 +0000: 5 лет
2022-02-24 17:38:38 +0000: 6 лет
....
```

Comment: Interesting. I just tried it, and if you use the `NSDateComponentsFormatter` function `stringFromDateComponents` with a French locale, you get  "1 année'" and "2 années", not "2 ans". (looks like `stringFromDateComponents` gives "années" for all plural years in French.)  I wonder why `stringFromDate` and `stringFromDateComponents` give different results?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is support for localized timespan strings built into Cocoa. I did some searching, and did find this Github project that does what you want:

https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo

It looks like it supports over 30 languages. It looks like it supports languages with non-roman symbols like Chinese, Japanese, Hebrew, Arabic, etc. That's tricky to do well, since those languages use very different systems, different layout rules, etc.

### Edit:

I just learned about the 'NSDateComponentsFormatter' class. It looks like that is a system class that will give you what you need.

Comment: It doesn't appear that this has what's needed here. The project's [French strings file](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo/blob/master/NSDateTimeAgo.bundle/fr.lproj/NSDateTimeAgo.strings) doesn't include anything that would produce "23 années", for example.

Comment: I'd suggest looking for other open source libraries, or maybe modify this one?

Comment: See me edit. 'NSDateComponentsFormatter' looks like it will do what you need.